# Wrong read from a named pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, named-pipes

I have a script which reads commands from a named pipe:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
host_pipe="host-pipe"

#pipe for executing commands
[ -p "$host_pipe" ] || mkfifo -m 0600 "$host_pipe" || exit 1 
chmod o+w "$host_pipe"

set -o pipefail

while :; do
    if read -r cmd <$host_pipe; then
        if [ "$cmd" ]; then
            printf 'Running: %s \n' "$cmd"
        fi
    fi
done
```

I run it and test with command:

```
bash -c "echo 'abcdef' > host-pipe"
bash -c "echo 'abcdef' > host-pipe"
bash -c "echo 'abcdef' > host-pipe"
bash -c "echo 'abcdef' > host-pipe"
```

And get the strange output:

```
Running: abcdf 
Running: abcdef 
Running: abcde 
Running: abcdf 
Running: ace
```

Somehow the script can't read all the string it get from the pipe? How to read it?

Comment: Which `bash` version are you running this on? Can't reproduce this on GNU `bash` v4.4

Comment: Couple of nitpicks - 1. You don't have to use a sub-shell to write to the fifo, just `echo 'abcdef' > host-pipe` should be sufficient 2. Also don't do `[ "$cmd" ]` for checking the string is empty or not, you are lucky, the string was quoted, but an unquoted string under `[..]` could have undesirable results. Use `[ ! -z "$cmd" ]` or `[[ $cmd ]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have more than one reader of the named pipe `host-pipe` running for this to happen.

Check to see if you have a second instance of the script running in the background or possibly in another terminal.

### Explanation

You will find that `bash` will issue reads from the pipe 1 byte at a time.  If you are on Linux, you can `strace` your script.  Here is an excerpt:

```
open("host-pipe", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                 = 10
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)        = 0
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0xbf99bfec)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(0, 0, 0xbf99c068, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(0, "a", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "b", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "c", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "d", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "e", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "f", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
fcntl64(10, F_GETFD)                    = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
```

Once you have more than one process with this consumption pattern, any single process will see lost characters.

Comment: Oh, you are right! I had another instance of the script in the background.